# Color changes of all objects. How to change a color on tap in specific object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have Container with objects, and my objects are rendered from Firebase. I change a color of container on tap, and it works. But, when I have a several objects, it changes colors of all containers. But I need to change a color of current (tapping) container.

```
Container(
  key: Key(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id),
  child: GestureDetector(
         onLongPress: () {
             setState(() {
                 cpressed = !cpressed;
                    });
                    },
         child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 0, milliseconds: 200),
                color: cpressed ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                child: Container(
                        child: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('item'), style: 
                               TextStyle(color: CWhite, fontSize: 24)),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 15, 0, 15)
                    )
                 ),
           )
       )
```

I have tried to put my `key: Key(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id)` as a property in AnimatedContainer, but it still doesn't work.

What can I do? I assume, It has to be something with keys, or, my setState()?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a boolean to determine which is selected, how about using the `id` instead?

Change `cpressed` to:

```
String? selectedId;
```

And the widget:

```
Container(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        var currentId = snapshot.data!.docs[index].id;
        setState(() {
          if (selectedId != null) {
            if (selectedId == currentId) {
              selectedId = null;
            } else {
              selectedId = currentId;
            }
          } else {
            selectedId = currentId;
          }
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 0, milliseconds: 200),
          color: selectedId == snapshot.data!.docs[index].id ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
          child: Container(
              child: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('item'), style:
              TextStyle(color: CWhite, fontSize: 24)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 15, 0, 15)
          )
      ),
    )
)
```

Comment: OMG u did it! It works! I am so happy, thanks a lot! + to ur karma from mine

Comment: Oops, but I have the other issue now ;) When I try to colorize the other container, my first-colored container loses his color. So, there no way to colorize two or more object at the same time.

Comment: u can store a list of selected ids and check if the list contains the id